# Atualizar conteúdo de arquivo JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Estou tentando manipular um arquivo JSON usando Python porém sempre que eu rodo o programa ele apaga o arquivo JSON fazendo com que eu perca a ultima alteração, tem como fazer ele só adicionar ao arquivo?

Arquivo:

```
{
  "PERGUNTA 1": "RESPOSTA",
  "PERGUNTA 2": "RESPOSTA",
  "PERGUNTA 3": "RESPOSTA",
  "PERGUNTA 4": "RESPOSTA",
}
```

Função que salva no arquivo:

```
guardar = {pergunta.upper():resposta}
with open('dados.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as gravar_file:
     json.dump(guardar, gravar_file,ensure_ascii=False,sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',',':'))
```

Sempre que rodo esse trecho de código eu perco as outras perguntas que eu tinha no meu arquivo.

Mudei o argumento de `w` para `a`:

```
try:
    guardar = {pergunta.upper():resposta}
    with open('dados.json', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as gravar_file:
        json.dumps(guardar, gravar_file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4, separators=(',',':'))
        print('Pergunta guardada!')
except:
      print('Não consegui aprender...')
      aprender()
```

Porém, agora após executar a função acima o meu JSON fica da seguinte forma:

```
{
  "PERGUNTA 1": "RESPOSTA",
  "PERGUNTA 2": "RESPOSTA",
  "PERGUNTA 3": "RESPOSTA",
  "PERGUNTA 4": "RESPOSTA",
}{
  "PERGUNTA 5": "RESPOSTA"
}
```

E ele ainda dá erro pois o Python não colocou a `,` para separar os objetos.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Sim é possível, basta mudar o modo de abertura para escrita do arquivo.
Utilizando o seu código:

```
with open('dados.json', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as gravar_file:
#resto do código
```

Repare que nesta solução a diferença é o modo de leitura dos arquivos. Estamos abrindo o arquivo para escrever, utilizando a estratégia de escrever no final do arquivo.

O modo de leitura é o segundo parâmetro da função open, quando utilizamos o modo `w`, estamos abrindo o arquivo para escrita, porém limpando o conteúdo anterior.
Quando abrimos utilizando o modo `a` estamos abrindo o arquivo para escrita, porém escrevendo sempre ao final do arquivo.

```
+---+--------------------------------------+
| w | limpa o conteúdo e escreve valores   |
+---+--------------------------------------+
| a | abre o arquivo para escrita no final |
+---+--------------------------------------+
```

Para aprender mais sobre quais os métodos de abertura de arquivo, recomendo [visualizar a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: Bom dia! Isso foi uma solução porem tive outro problema kkk
a minha variável que contem o dict que vai ser guardado no json está da seguinte forma
guardar = {pergunta.upper():resposta} e quando eu salvo ela no json, ele cria outra chave fazendo assim dar erro no json.
Eu queria adicionar ela na chave ja existente pois o meu json é simples ele so tem uma chave e eu so queria adicionar outros valores nele. qual seria a solução pra isso?

Comment: Cara, eu não sei se entendi o problema, mas em python se vc tem uma variável dentro de chaves isso é um dict. Se vc quer salvar um json, deveria fazer o import da classe `json` e para salvar json vc usaria a função json.dumps(objetoagravar). Passando um objeto a gravar.

Comment: vou editar a perguntar e colocar a função

Comment: Editei a pergunta

Answer (score 5):

O problema é que somente escrever os dados no final do arquivo não é o suficiente para fazer o que você precisa.

Ao escrever no final do arquivo com a opção `'a'`, você está escrevendo apenas o conteúdo da nova pergunta, ignorando a semântica do conteúdo do arquivo (na verdade a nova pergunta deveria ser adicionada ao objeto JSON já existente, em vez de ser escrito logo depois).

Ou seja, o arquivo já tem um objeto JSON contendo várias perguntas. Em vez de adicionar uma pergunta neste objeto, o que você fez foi escrever outro objeto logo depois. Por isso o arquivo ficou desse jeito:

```
{
  "PERGUNTA 1": "RESPOSTA",
  "PERGUNTA 2": "RESPOSTA",
  "PERGUNTA 3": "RESPOSTA",
  "PERGUNTA 4": "RESPOSTA",
}{
  "PERGUNTA 5": "RESPOSTA"
}
```

E se você tentar lê-lo novamente, dará erro, porque isso não é um JSON válido (já que agora são 2 objetos diferentes, em vez de apenas um: o primeiro objeto tem as perguntas de 1 a 4, e o segundo objeto tem a pergunta 5).

Mas pelo que entendi, o que você queria era um único objeto contendo todas as 5 perguntas:

```
{
  "PERGUNTA 1": "RESPOSTA",
  "PERGUNTA 2": "RESPOSTA",
  "PERGUNTA 3": "RESPOSTA",
  "PERGUNTA 4": "RESPOSTA",
  "PERGUNTA 5": "RESPOSTA"
}
```

---

Uma opção para resolver seria abrir o arquivo e carregar todo o seu conteúdo com [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load), obtendo assim o respectivo objeto. Depois você atualiza este objeto com a nova pergunta e sobrescreve o arquivo.

Mas em vez de escrever diretamente no mesmo arquivo, creio que seja melhor primeiro escrever o conteúdo em um arquivo temporário, e só no final, se tudo der certo, você renomeia o arquivo temporário. Assim, se ocorrer um erro durante a escrita, o arquivo original é preservado (pois o erro só afetará o arquivo temporário). Ficaria assim:

```
import json
import shutil
import tempfile

with open('dados.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as arq, \
     tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', delete=False) as out:
    # ler todo o arquivo e obter o objeto JSON
    dados = json.load(arq)
    # atualizar os dados com a nova pergunta
    dados["PERGUNTA 5"] = "RESPOSTA"
    # escreve o objeto atualizado no arquivo temporário
    json.dump(dados, out, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4, separators=(',',':'))

# se tudo deu certo, renomeia o arquivo temporário
shutil.move(out.name, 'dados.json')
```

Para criar o arquivo temporário, usei o [módulo `tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html). Com isso, após o código rodar, o conteúdo do arquivo será:

```
{
    "PERGUNTA 1":"RESPOSTA",
    "PERGUNTA 2":"RESPOSTA",
    "PERGUNTA 3":"RESPOSTA",
    "PERGUNTA 4":"RESPOSTA",
    "PERGUNTA 5":"RESPOSTA"
}
```

Este método funciona também para outros casos, como por exemplo apagar uma das perguntas, ou atualizar o texto delas (pois aí o arquivo pode ficar menor que o original, então somente escrever no final não seria a ação mais adequada).

---

Um detalhe, o seu arquivo original **não** pode ter a vírgula depois da pergunta 4, senão ela será um JSON inválido:

```
{
  "PERGUNTA 1": "RESPOSTA",
  "PERGUNTA 2": "RESPOSTA",
  "PERGUNTA 3": "RESPOSTA",
  "PERGUNTA 4": "RESPOSTA", <-- esta vírgula está errada, e deve ser removida
}
```

---

Por fim, se a ideia é que o arquivo sirva para persistir os dados, mas não necessariamente precise ser lido por uma pessoa, considere usar os módulos [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) ou [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) - este último em especial parece ser mais adequado à sua necessidade. Uma ideia seria primeiro converter o seu JSON original para o formato do `shelve`:

```
import json
import shelve

# primeira vez, carregar o arquivo JSON e criar o arquivo no formato do shelve
with open('dados.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as arq, \
     shelve.open('dados_shelve.json') as novos_dados:
    dados = json.load(arq)
    novos_dados.update(dados)
```

Depois, basta atualizar o novo arquivo usando o próprio `shelve`:

```
# da segunda vez em diante, basta ler o arquivo com shelve
with shelve.open('dados_shelve.json') as dados:
    # a linha abaixo já atualiza o arquivo
    dados["PERGUNTA 5"] = "RESPOSTA"
```

A diferença é que o `shelve` cria arquivos binários, e não um texto bonitinho como o arquivo JSON. Mas se a ideia é somente persistir os dados e ir atualizando-os, sem que uma pessoa precise lê-lo, esta é uma boa alternativa.

Comment: olá estava olhando seu código pois estava com a mesma dificuldade do autor da pergunta, e me ficou uma dúvida. shutil.move(out.name, 'dados.json'). Nesta parte do código, porque usastes "out.name"?

Comment: @HenriqueFH `out.name` é o nome do arquivo temporário. Sem isso o `move` não saberia qual arquivo renomear

Answer (score 0):

Posso te ajudar com a logica:

> Carregue o conteúdo do arquivo

> Transforme o conteúdo em JSON

> Altere o objeto json em memoria

> Salve o objeto JSON ('sobreescrevendo o arquivo')

dessa forma você não precisara se preocupar em fazer seu código escrever a sintaxe correta pois ao transformar o JSON em string a sintaxy vai estar correta

Carregue o conteúdo do arquivo

```py
    arquivo = open("dados.json", "r")
```

transforme o conteúdo do arquivo em um objeto JSON

```py
import json
conteudo = json.load(arquivo)
```

Manipule o Objeto Json

`... o que vc quiser fazer....`

Salve o objeto JSON ('sobreescrevendo o arquivo')

```py
arquivo.close() # Fecha o arquivo que estava aberto como somente leitura
arquivo = open("dados.json", "w") # Sobrescreve o arquivo
json.dump(conteudo, arquivo) # Salva o Json no arquivo
arquivo.close() # Fecha o arquivo
```

Comment: Se está lendo de um arquivo, vc pode fazer diretamente `json.load(arquivo)`. Não tem porque ler todas as linhas, juntá-las em uma string, e só depois fazer o `load` (é uma volta desnecessária). Outro detalhe é que se for converter uma string, deve usar `json.loads(string)` (load**s** em vez de load, senão dará erro). Para escrever, mesma coisa: não precisa criar uma string e depois escrevê-la no arquivo, pode fazer só `json.dump(objetoJson, arquivo)`.

Comment: Mas o problema principal é que vc abriu o arquivo com a opção `'w'`, que abre o arquivo para escrita, além de apagar todo o conteúdo do mesmo (ou seja, não vai conseguir ler). Aliás, esse é um dos problemas citados na pergunta: "*Sempre que rodo esse trecho de código eu perco as outras perguntas que eu tinha no meu arquivo*"

Comment: Seu primeiro comentário concordo plenamente, porem no segundo comentário é possivel abrir como somente ´r´ pega o json fecha e na hroa de salvar abrir com ´w´

Comment: Então edite a resposta e faça isso :-)

Comment: Editado. ( era uma afirmação/pergunta)