# Como eu faço para adicionar informações a um arquivo json existente usando python?

Tags: banco-de-dados, python-3.x, json

Estou tentando criar uma função para salvar dados em um arquivo json no python e não to conseguindo fazer isso sem que os dados anteriores sejam substituídos pelos novos (quero que os antigos permaneçam e que os novos sejam adicionados logo depois).

Também não consigo manter os dados antigos junto com os novos sem que o json se torne inválido, já que o modo "a" não adiciona vírgula após o primeiro objeto antes de adicionar o novo...

Estive tentando fazer como eu vi em alguns lugares: carregar o arquivo json, adicionar o conteúdo novo e salvar ele de novo no arquivo, mas não estou conseguindo construir a função sem que dê erro.

a minha função está assim com as sugestões dos comentários:

```py
def salvar_dados(nomedojson, file):
    if not isfile(nomedojson):  # Verifica se o arquivo já existe, se não existir ele vai criar
        with open(nomedojson, "w", encoding="utf-8") as dados:
            lista = []
            lista.append(file)
            salvando1 = json.dump(lista, dados, indent=2, separators=(",", ": "), sort_keys=True)
            return salvando1
    else:  # condição que atesta que o arquivo já existe e só precisa ser atualizado
        with open(nomedojson, "r+", encoding="utf-8") as dados:
            carregando = [json.load(dados)]  # comando para carregar o arquivo existente
            atualizando = carregando.append(file)  # comando para supostamente atualizar o conteúdo
            salvando2 = json.dump(atualizando, dados, indent=2, separators=(",", ": "), sort_keys=True)
            return salvando2
```

E aparece o seguinte erro:

[image: erro que aparece com a execução do código]

amostra de dados:

```
 dic_p = {self.nome_completo[0]+" "+self.nome_completo[1]: {'Nome': self.nome[0], 'Sobrenome': self.sobrenome[0]}}
```

Queria que ficasse assim:

[image: arquivo json]

(eu inseri à mão só pra mostrar, não consigo deixar dessa forma rodando o código)

Mas ta ficando assim:

[image: json inválido]

Já faz 3 dias que tento resolver esse problema, estou ficando sem ideias do que testar... Se alguém puder ajudar eu agradeço!

Comment: Na pergunta sugerida acima, a primeira resposta não é a mais indicada por acabar tendo o mesmo problema que vc teve (de gerar um JSON inválido ao adicionar dados no arquivo). Eu sugiro que dê uma olhada na outra resposta, me parece ser o que vc precisa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/467156/112052

Comment: Foi exatamente nesse link que eu inspirei a mudar o código para o que ele é como eu apresentei nesta pergunta que fiz agora. não tenho como fazer o código exatamente como vc a respondeu porque eu quero adicionar dicionários dentro de dicionários e não perguntas e respostas.

Comment: Mas a ideia é a mesma, não importa se o dicionário tem outros dicionários dentro ou seja lá o que for. Pelo que entendi, dá pra usar exatamente o mesmo código de lá: se `dados` é um dicionário, não importa o que tem nele, a forma de salvar e atualizar é a mesma

Comment: Coloque na pergunta uma amostra dos dados do arquivo e dos dados que deseja inserir.

Comment: Ah, agora está explicado: o que vc quer salvar não é um JSON, são na verdade 2 objetos "soltos", independentes - tem explicação [aqui](/a/421569/112052), mas resumindo, `{alguma coisa}, {outra coisa}` são 2 objetos soltos (um contendo "alguma coisa", e outro contendo "outra coisa"), por isso não funciona salvar tudo como um único JSON. O que vc poderia fazer é colocar todos esses objetos diferentes em uma lista (aí o arquivo ficaria como um único JSON, só que em um array)

Comment: as respostas estão em outra linguagem de programação, e eu só sei python. Como eu posso fazer uma lista de objetos no json usando python?

Comment: É só colocá-los em uma lista: `lista = [objeto1, objeto2, objeto3]` - ou então `lista = []` e depois `lista.append(objeto1)`, `lista.append(objeto2)`, etc. E depois salve a lista no arquivo, passando-a para `json.dump` (e usando os métodos sugeridos na resposta já indicada para evitar os problemas de sobrescrever o arquivo)

Comment: atualizei o código com as sugestões que me deu, mas ainda dá erro...

Comment: Também tentei a lógica de carregar o conteúdo do arquivo apenas para leitura com o r, transformar o conteúdo em JSON, alterar o objeto json em memoria com o append, chamar o modo de escrita com o w, salvar o objeto JSON sobreescrevendo o arquivo, e o resultado? Null ...

Answer (score 1):

Eu quero agradecer a todos que dedicaram alguns minutos do seu tempo pra me ajudar, hoje eu finalmente consegui fazer o meu código rodar para salvar os dados da forma que eu preciso. Então, para não deixar futuros visitantes sem resposta vou contar a minha solução:

Eu reformulei a função de carregar e de salvar os arquivos e os deixei dessa forma:

```
def salvar_dados(nomedojson, file):
with open(nomedojson, "w", encoding="utf-8") as dados:
    salvando = json.dump(file, dados, indent=2, separators=(",", ": "), sort_keys=True)
    return salvando

def carregar_dados(nomedojson):
if isfile(nomedojson):  # Verifica se o arquivo já existe, se sim, o json será carregado
    with open(nomedojson, "r", encoding="utf-8") as dados:
        return json.load(dados)
else:  # Se o json ainda não existe, a função cria e retorna uma lista
    temporario = []
    return temporario
```

Então eu faço a função carregar o arquivo antes de todo o programa iniciar:

```
try:
    dados_p = carregar_dados("Banco de dados1.json")
    dados_s = carregar_dados("Banco de dados2.json")
    dados_c = carregar_dados("Banco de dados3.json")
    # Se os jsons ainda não existirem, uma lista para cada um será retornada
except Exception as erro:
    print("Ocorreu um erro durante o carregamento: ", erro)
```

Após carregar os jsons (ou as listas), aparece um menu principal, aonde o usuário pode efetuar cadastros e consultas nos arquivos json.

Um detalhe muito importante é usar as mesmas variáveis "dados_p", "dados_s" e "dados_c" para efetuar e salvar as alterações nos arquivos json utilizando o comando append. Ex: "dados_p.append(file)"

É isso, demorei muito pra aprender a fazer esse tipo de coisa. Espero que eu tenha conseguido ser clara na minha pergunta e na minha resposta à pergunta. Mais uma vez, muito obrigada aos que dedicaram a atenção pra me ajudar! Espero também poder ajudar quem estiver com o mesmo problema.