# Dicionário dentro do arquivo JSON

Tags: python, json

Estou tentando escrever um arquivo JSON em forma de dicionário, para assim criar uma função de pesquisa que me retorne o valor da pesquisa, porém quando crio a função de adicionar palavra ele me retorna isso:

```
{
"love": "amor"
}{"how": "como"
}
```

Esse é o formato que estou usando:

```
def Adiciona_Palavras():
    while True:
        add_palavra = input("Digite a palavra ou S para sair ao menu: ")
        if add_palavra == "s":
            break
        add_retorno = input(("Digite a tradução ou S para sair ao menu: "))
        with open("Dicionário_palavras.json","a") as arquivo:
            json.dump({add_palavra:add_retorno},arquivo)
```

Preciso que essa função adicione palavras assim:

```
{
"love": "amor",
"how": "como"
}
```

Comment: A cada iteração vc cria um novo dicionário. Se quer apenas um, crie o dicionário antes do `while`, e dentro do loop vc só atualiza ele, adicionando os dados necessários. E depois que o loop se encerrar (ou seja, fora do `while`) vc escreve no arquivo. Talvez ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/467156/112052

Comment: valeu meu amigo, consegui resolver o problema.

Comment: def salvar_palavras():
    while True:
        with open("Dicionário_palavras.json", "r") as leitura:
            l = json.load(leitura)
            print("Você está no Armazenamento de  Palavras\n")
            a = input("Digite a palavra ou S para sair ao menu: ")
            if a == "s":
                break
            b = input(("Digite a tradução: "))
            l[a] = b
            with open("Dicionário_palavras.json", "w") as novo:
                json.dump(l, novo,indent=1)

Answer (score 0):

O erro ocorre porque você está abrindo o arquivo no modo de adição ("a"):

`with open("Dicionário_palavras.json","a") as arquivo:`

O que faz com que cada chamada json.dump adicione um novo bloco JSON ao final do arquivo existente.

Para corrigir isso, você pode seguir uma abordagem onde você lê o conteúdo atual do arquivo, atualiza o dicionário e, em seguida, escreve novamente o conteúdo atualizado no arquivo. Fiz uma modificação no código que funciona como você espera:

```
import json

def Adiciona_Palavras():
    dicionario = {}
    
    #Abre o arquivo e adiciona as palavras.
    try:
        with open("Dicionário_palavras.json", "r") as arquivo:
            dicionario = json.load(arquivo)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        #Se o arquivo não existir, cria um dicionário vazio
        pass

    while True:
        add_palavra = input("Digite a palavra ou S para sair ao menu: ")
        if add_palavra.lower() == "s":
            break
        add_retorno = input(("Digite a tradução ou S para sair ao menu: "))
        
        #Adiciona a palavra e a tradução ao dicionário
        dicionario[add_palavra] = add_retorno

    #Escreve o dicionário atualizado no arquivo com a indentação que deseja
    with open("Dicionário_palavras.json", "w") as arquivo:
        json.dump(dicionario, arquivo, indent=4)

Adiciona_Palavras()
```

Resultado:

```
{
    "AMOR": "LOVE",
    "ODIO": "HATE",
    "love": "amor",
    "hate": "odio"
}
```